# "Stability" of the relative cap product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology", he introduces the relative version of the cap product:

$$
- \cap {-} : \mathrm{H}^{p}(X, A) \otimes \mathrm{H}_{p + q}(X, A \cup B) \to \mathrm{H}_{q}(X, B) 
$$

Let us restrict our attention to singular (co)homology and let me suppress the coefficients.

He then goes on to state a number of properties about this operation without proof. Most follow easily from previously established results about the action of $\cap$ on (co)chains. A pair of them, stability, is a bit more involved and I'm having trouble proving them. I've reproduced the pair of properties below

Let us fix a pair $A, B \subseteq X$ which we suppose to be excisive, $j_B : (B, A \cap B) \to (X, A)$ and $j_A : (A, A \cap B) \to (X, B)$ the inclusions, and a pair of maps induced by excision:

\begin{align*}
  \partial_A : \mathsf{H}_{p + q}(X, A \cup B) \to \mathsf{H}_{p + q - 1}(A \cup B, B) \cong \mathsf{H}_{p + q - 1}(A, A \cap B)
\\
  \partial_B : \mathsf{H}_{p + q}(X, A \cup B) \to \mathsf{H}_{p + q - 1}(A \cup B, B) \cong \mathsf{H}_{p + q - 1}(B, A \cap B)
\end{align*}

Now tom Dieck claims the following properties hold for the cap product:

1. Given $x \in \mathsf{H}^p(X, A)$ and $y \in \mathsf{H}_{p + q}(X, A \cup B)$ then
   $$
   j^*_B x \cap \partial_B y = (-1)^p \partial(x \cap y) \in \mathsf{H}_{q - 1}(B)
   $$
2. Given $x \in \mathsf{H}^p(A)$ and $y \in \mathsf{H}_{p + q}(X, A \cup B)$ then
   $$
   j_{A*}(x \cap \partial_A y) = (-1)^{p + 1} \delta x \cap y \in \mathsf{H}_{q - 1}(X, B)
   $$

Intuitively, I believe that both of these properties should follow from the previous result established about the cap product on (co)chains:
$$
\partial (\phi \cap \sigma) = \delta \phi \cap \sigma + (-1)^{|\phi|} \phi \cap \partial \sigma
$$
My guess is that both of these properties can be reduced to elementary calculations on chains + this result, but the bookkeeping is eluding me. Am I on the right track? Do both of these properties follow from this result? I'm particularly interested in (2), since (1) seems a bit easier.

(If writing these calculations out is as painful as I expect, is there are more fleshed out account of these properties given in some other source that I can reference?)